# Casting return value to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose we have an interface with a single generic method:

```
public interface IExtender
{
    T GetValue<T>(string tag);
}
```

and a simple implementation A of it that returns instances of two different types (B and C) depending on the "tag" parameter:

```
public class A : IExtender
{
    public T GetValue<T>(string tag)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(B) && tag == null)
            return (T)(object) new B();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(C) && tag == "foo")
            return (T)(object) new C();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

is it possible to avoid the double cast `(T)(object)`? Or, is there a way to tell the compiler "hey, I am sure that this cast won't fail at runtime, just let me do it without first casting to object!"

Comment: Why you need (T)(Object) conversion? You can directly (T) new C() right?

Comment: @Anuraj: No - that's the whole point of the question. Please read the blog post referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Or, is there a way to tell the compiler "hey, I am sure that this cast won't fail at runtime, just let me do it without first casting to object!"

No, the language is deliberately designed to prevent this. Eric Lippert [blogged about this recently](https://ericlippert.com/2012/07/10/696/). I agree it's annoying, but it does make a certain kind of sense.

To be honest, "generic" methods like this are *usually* a bit of a design smell. If a method has to have special cases for various different types, you should at least consider using separate methods instead. (`GetB`, `GetC`)

Comment: Yup. GetB, GetC and GetEtc aren't an option here but I don't know if this is the right place to discuss the design at length. Anyway, the first paragraph and the link are the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is poossible, in more than one way,  and sometimes it is the only good soluition to a design problem. Which is why the dynamic keyword was introduced.  And Convert.ChangeType.

Comment: @DinoDini: I don't think either of those is actually doing what the OP is talking about. The OP doesn't *want* to perform any actual value conversion - they just want to avoid the double cast. Using dynamic effectively just makes the conversion to `object` implicit, but it doesn't remove it in any helpful way.

Comment: Blog link has gone dead, but I found it here https://ericlippert.com/2012/07/10/696/

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: Thanks, I've edited it now. For future similar situations, feel free to suggest the edit directly.

Answer (score 6):

```
public T MyMethod<T>(string tag) where T : class
    {
        return new A() as T;
    }
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This wouldn't work without restricting `T` to be a class. The other solution (below) with `dynamic` keyword does not have such limitation.

Answer (score 3):

check this sample:

```
    public T GetValue<T>(string tag) where T : class, new()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(B) && tag == null)
            return new T();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(C) && tag == "foo")
            return new T();
        return default(T);
    }
```

no cast needed, you can create instance of "T", just add the generic constraint that saying that T is a class and it have parameterless constructor so you don't need to create another base types and you can be sure that only suitable types will go through this generic method.

Comment: Well, this is what happens when you (me, really) try to simplify the code to post as example. In the real code the instances already exist and I can't put any constraint on T. So yes, this works (thanks!) but doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic to store your real result, but you have to be sure the generic argument type is the right type you return.

```
TResult GetResult<TResult>() 
{
    dynamic r = 10;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: The actual answer. At the bottom of the page. Again.

Comment: This doesn't really remove the cast - it just makes it implicit instead of explicit. It's also likely to perform rather less well than the double cast.

Comment: This did work as a workaround for me.  If the programmer checks the type themselves, I don't see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The only way to do so would be to let the compiler know about additional assumptions on `T`. As evidenced by [the list of generic parameter constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), there is no constraint defined in C# to require availability of a specific cast.

Comment: It is possible with dynamic casting.

Answer (score 0):

if you let B and C implement the same interface you could use a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on your `T`. Probably not exactly what you want, but as suggested also by others what you want is not really possible.

```
public interface IclassBndC {}

public class B : IclassBandC {}

public class C : IclassBandC {}

public class A : IExtender
{
    public T GetValue<T>(string tag) where T : IclassBandC 
    {
        if (tag == null)
            return new B();
        if (tag == "foo")
            return new C();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this requires that you can modify `B` and `C`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true, did I miss a mentioning of that not being possible?

Comment: You didn't, but there was no mention that `B` and `C` are written by the OP rather than pre-defined and sealed, either. Just thought the restriction should be mentioned.